# Best way to build extendable system

Tags: php, oop, architecture

I'm developing a PHP CMS and I have question about flexible and «extendable» architecture.

I want to allow users to «extend» every class in system.
For example, if I have class `User`:

```
<?php
namespace MyCMSName\Extensions\Users;

class User
{
    public function getUserAvatar()
    {
        // return file path, for example
    }
}
```

Now I want to do something with users avatars. Return different image for each user, for example.

```
<?php
namespace MyCMSName\Extensions\FakeUserAvatars;

class User extends MyCMSName\Extensions\Users\User
{
    public function getUserAvatar()
    {
        // return another path
    }
}
```

But somewhere in system I have User object constructing. I need to create `FakeUserAvatars\User`, not original `Users\User` object.

```
...
$user = new (? How can I determine which class to construct?)
```

Should I create something about map «original class → extended class» and then generate it when installing new extensions? Then I can get class which overload original and create new instance. But what about autoloading? It seems that I should have custom function for load every class in system if I want to make it «extendable».

What do you think?
Sorry if I wrote something wrong, English isn't my native language...

Comment: You don't use `new`: use a factory to instantiate all your classes instead.... the factory (working with an autoloader) can look to see if there is a user extended version of the requested class, and instantiate that if there is, else instantiate your core version

Comment: You will need to (or be best served by) implement dependency injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection, Symfony2 is all about this in many ways.

Comment: @MarkBaker it means that I should create «system-wide» factory and then use it something like `$user = SystemFactory::getObjectFor('MyCMSName\Extensions\Users\User')` ?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes

Comment: @WasimAbu-Nassar is what you are making a "developer cms" or an "end-user cms"?

Comment: @tereško currently it for me firstly. I have an idea for social project and I want to develop it from scratch because I want to get programming practice both in backend and frontend (:
And I want to build nice-looking system which I can support in the future, so I wanted to get advice about my architecture ideas.